# ocultar códigos java.class al importar en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Al importar mi aplicación java como biblioteca en Netbeans se logra ver todo el codigo . alguien sabe si se puede ocultar?

Answer (score 0):

El truco está al exportar.

Netbeans es un IDE que se supone que te hace la vida más fácil, hace muchas cosas en automático. Para los que estamos acostumbrados a Eclipse, algunas cosas sencillas (como ésta), las vuelve enredadas, a mi punto de vista.

Pero no tanto.

Si te vas a la vista de "Files" en lugar de "Projects", desde ahí en el directorio "TuProyecto/dist/", puedes encontrar el war que Netbeans genera automáticamente cada vez que lo compilas (haces Build). Éste war, cuando lo abres, únicamente trae los archivos binarios (.class)

Si no logras abrir la vista "Files", ve al navegador de archivos de tu máquina y desde ahí localiza dicho war.

Ahora sí, tu war lo puedes enviar, o hacer lo que quieras, sin que tenga ninguna de tus archivos fuente (.java)

[image: Ubicación del war, desde Files]